# Quick Shortcut to skim through web search results

Tags: safari, google-chrome, shortcut

I wish to utilize all the shortcuts I can, but I'm not sure how it is called in the first place. (that must be why I cannot find the shortcut for it by searching..)

I've seen a friend use it to speed up going through search results instead of using the mouse key to scroll and click, but it is too long ago. I've tried several combinations to no avail. [Keyboard preference] on the menu was not quite informative.

How do you go through search items on the same tab just using shortcut on Mac? (Safari or Chrome, if different)

For instance, you will see an arrow next to the search result (lets say I am to see the 2nd return result) you have stopped at. At which point you can just press Enter to view.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you just want to be able to go down the page in sections rather than scroll? Spacebar will do that [so long as you don't have any text area selected]

Comment: tab key can help too. I do tab, then enter, if wrong page, cmd + [ for back and tab again for next result(if it stays there, in some sites.)

Answer (score 2):

In Safari `⌥ + Tab` appears to select every link through google. Tried it in DuckDuckGo and I don't get the same behavior but if you search and just use the up and down arrow keys without clicking anything it selects the various links.

Chrome it appears you may need an extension such as [Google Search Keyboard Shortcuts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-keyboard-sh/iobmefdldoplhmonnnkchglfdeepnfhd?hl=en)